# Eclipse test-run looking for classes in different directory than build is placing them

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, maven, objectify

I recently make the switch from [Objectify 3.1](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify) to [Objectify 4.0](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Introduction) which involved a switch to Maven.  The build puts the output .class files under war/WEB_INF/classes and the app runs just fine both locally and on App-Engine.

My problem is that when I run my *test* target, it can't find any of my test classes because it is trying to load them from the target/classes directory.  If I switch the default output directory temporarily to that, the tests run fine but then of course the real target won't run (class definitions not found at run-time under war/WEB-INF/classes).

I tried to delete the target/classes directory and maybe link it to the new location but Eclipse immediately recreates it as soon as I remove it.

*Am I doing something wrong?  How to I make the test target read classes from the designated output directory?*

**Update 2013-12-21:** If I look at the "Source" information for both the App-Engine run-config and the associated tests run-config, both have (under the project name) a "target" entry with sub-entries of "classes" and "test-classes".  It *also* has a "war/WEB-INF" entry with sub-entries of "classes" and "lib".  Unfortunately, I can't seem to delete the former set and I have no idea what is causing it to be there.

**Update 2013-12-30:** Here is my `pom.xml` file...

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>DeityAE</groupId>
  <artifactId>DeityAE</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
      <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.8.8</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Found this on the web but doesn't seem to be working. -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.8</version>
        <executions>
          <execute>
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${basedir}/war/WEB-INF/lib/</outputDirectory>
              <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
              <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
              <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
              <excludeArtifactIds>gwt-user,gwt-dev</excludeArtifactIds>
            </configuration>
          </execute>
        </executions>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
        <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.8</version>
    </dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
      <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
      <version>4.0rc2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Objectify does not do any runtime inspection of class files; this is an eclipse (and google plugin for eclipse) classpath issue. Or an issue with whatever tool you are using to run the tests (maven? ant?).

Comment: Hmmm...  Something else must need it then.  For whatever reason, it has to be under war/WEB-INF/classes.  Why is the test target trying to read them from target/classes?

Comment: Could you please post your build's tag content from pom please?

Comment: Have you specified the <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory> in your pom.xml ?

Comment: @vzamanillo, pom.xml posted.  I don't have a `testSourceDirectory` set because my tests are in the same tree.  The problem does not appear to be building because I can see the FooTest.class files appearing under war/WEB-INF/classes but rather the test-runner finding them in that location.

Comment: Try adding the testOutputDirectory tag to the build section in pom.

Comment: Not sure if `testOutputDirectory` affects only their output placement (which is already correct) or if it also affects the classpath parameter in the "Run configuration" for the test (which is what eventually fixed it for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

- Go to "Run configurations..."
- select target (e.g. `MyProjectTests`)
- select "Classpath" tab
- select "User Entries"
- click the "Advanced..." button
- choose "Add Folders"
- browse to `war/WEB-INF/classes` and click "OK"
- "Apply" and "Run"

Answer (score 0):

In mine, The working configuration's .classpath file contains something like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
.
.
.
</classpath>
```

I think it is to do with `.classpath` file of individual projects (if you have multiple projects). And please note that it will not be visible by default under linux, you have to **open file** from **file** menu and type .classpath in addressbar.

Comment: The .classpath file has two ".../classpath" entries and both are set to `war/WEB-INF/classes`.  If I run Maven "Update..." on the project, it sets both to `target/classes` after which the tests will run but the actual project will not launch either locally or an app-engine -- many classes are not found.